# Moeda em Site Asp Net MVC

Tags: mvc, asp

Criei meu site em asp net padrao MVC e percebi que quando rodo o site local na minha máquina com Windows-PTBR aparece a moeda corrente do site (que é um e-commerce) como Real R$. Ao hospedar meu site em uma hospedagem gringa, percebi que a moeda corrente aparece em dólar $. Estou tentando a alguns dias descobrir como converter para R$ mas não estou conseguindo. 
O campo com a informação é esse. Utilizo o "c" para gerar a moeda.

```
<td class="text-center">@item.Produto.Preco.ToString("c")</td>
```

Comment: E mão pode mudar a configuração lá? Boas hospedagens permitem que você tenha seu ambiente adequado.

Comment: é uma hospedagem gratis que eu uso pra testar meu site Asp Net, gearhost.com

Comment: Você pode definir na sua aplicação qual culture vai usar também